# Merge Pandas Dataframe using "to_frame" without duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am merging one column from DataFrame (df1) with another DataFrame (df2 where both have the same index. The result of this operation gives me a lot more rows that I started with (duplicates). Is there a way to avoid duplicates? Please see the example codes below to replicate my issue.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1.0, 2.3,0.2,0.53], [2, 3.35, 2.0,0.2,0.65], [2,3.4, 
                   2.0,0.25,0.55]],
                   columns=["Sample_ID", "NaX", "NaU","OC","EC"])\
                   .set_index('Sample_ID')   

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,0.2, 1.5, 82], [2, 3.35,2.4,92],[2, 3.4, 2.0,0.25]],
                columns=["Sample_ID", "OC","Flow", "Diameter"])\
                .set_index('Sample_ID')

df1 = pd.merge(df1,df2['Flow'].to_frame(), left_index=True,right_index=True)
```

My result (below) has two entries for sample "2" starting with 3.35 and then two entries for "2" starting with 3.40.

What I was expecting was just two entries for "2", one starting with 3.35 and the other line for "2" starting with 3.40. So the total number of rows should be only three, while I have a total of 5 rows of data now.

Can you please see what the reason for this is? Thanks for your help!

```
        NaX NaU OC  EC  Flow 
 Sample_ID                  
    1   1.00    2.3 0.20    0.53    1.5
    2   3.35    2.0 0.20    0.65    2.4
    2   3.35    2.0 0.20    0.65    2.0
    2   3.40    2.0 0.25    0.55    2.4
    2   3.40    2.0 0.25    0.55    2.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is concatenate as follows:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2['Flow'].to_frame()], axis=1)
```

...which returns your desired output.  The `axis=1` argument let's you "glue on" extra columns.

As to why your join is returning twice as many entries for `Sample_ID = 2`, you can [read through the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) on joins.  The relevant portion is:

> In SQL / standard relational algebra, if a key combination appears more than once in both tables, the resulting table will have the Cartesian product of the associated data.